# Including generated code in JAR with Gradle

Tags: gradle

I wrote a simple gradle task to generate thrift files:

```
task generateThrift << {
  thriftFiles = fileTree(dir: 'src/main/thrift').matching { include '**/*.thrift' }
  exec {
    executable = 'thrift'
    args = ['--gen', 'java:hashcode', '-o', '/tmp', thriftFiles.collect { relativePath(it) }.join(",") ]
  }
}
```

This works fine for me.  What I want to do is hook it into the build process so the stubs are including in my JAR file.  I'm having trouble finding a good example of where to hook this in, and where to write the files out to so that they are included in my JAR.  What's the best way to do this or a project that has an example?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I suggest to write the files to a subdirectory of the build output directory, say `thrift-stubs`. Then you can include them in the Jar like so:

```
jar {
  from "$buildDir/thrift-stubs"
}
```

Comment: Peter - what's the syntax for this if the project also has code in src/main/java?

Comment: It stays the same. `jar` is a preconfigured task; the `from` only adds additional content.

Comment: Question on this. How would I go about copying multiple files from a specific directory? Let's say all xml files from a certain folder to be included into the jar?

Comment: Cannot get proper source code formatting to work in a comment. You should open a new question.